# Moving on the exact comment on the page on receiving a comment

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

As on Stack over flow if any user has commented I get a red count of notification on top and on clicking it,it lands me too the exact comment on the same page without scrolling down.

What is it called and how can I achieve this in Asp.Net MVC.

I tried to search it but am searching the wrong thing as am not aware of the term that is supposed to be used while searching.

Example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an HTML Bookmark, or Anchor.  Click on one of those notifications and look at the url.

For example:
`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320541/low-quality-review-why-is-this-answer-offensive-or-repulsive/320542#320542`

The last part is the anchor:
`#320542`

If you then go to that page and search for 320542, you'll see the anchor:

```
<a name="320542"></a>
```

This isn't ASP or MVC specific.  It's HTML.  To implement it, create a bookmark anchor on your page, and then refer to the anchor in your link url.